# Escape # in data uri

Tags: data-uri

How to escape `#` in data URI scheme. for eg: uri

```
data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{"asdf":"#value"}
```

Shows only up to `#`

```
{"asdf":"
```

and whatever comes after `#` is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an URI, it should use URI encoding. `#`  needs to be `%23` instead:

```
data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,{"asdf":"%23value"}
```